# Why can't I run a single line in my method only once?

Tags: python

So as part of a game, I have an animated text window that pops up and prints each word every second.

The problem here is the method "eachwordprint", is called repeatedly in the game, but I only want to run newmessage.text.split one time.  I would just put this in the init, but in the game, I am changing the string at different times, so I need to split the string each time I change the string.

I tried doing

```
if self.counter <=1:
    words = newmessage.text.split(' ')
```

but this doesn't work (I'm not sure why).  Any suggestions on how I can better achieve what I'm trying to do ?

```
class NewLabel(ButtonBehavior, Label):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(NewLabel, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.font_name='PressStart2P.ttf'
        self.font_size=16
        self.text=kwargs['text']
        self.text_size=(Window.width*.70, Window.height*.23)
        self.mipmp = True
        self.line_height=1.5
        self.markup = True
        self.counter=0
        #self.words = self.text.split(' ')



    def eachwordprint(self, *args):
        self.counter += 1
        if self.counter <=1:
            words = newmessage.text.split(' ')
        print "counter: ", self.counter
        print "word length", len(words)
        if self.counter <= 1:
            anim = Animation(size_hint=(1, .25), duration=1.8)
            anim.start(messagebox)
            self.text=''
        if len(words) > self.counter:
            self.text += words[self.counter]
            self.text += " "
        else:
            anim2 = Animation(size_hint=(1, 0), duration=1.8)
            anim2.start(messagebox)
            #messagebox.remove_widget(self)
            return False

newmessage = "this is a test hello. this is a test."
```

Comment: "This doesn't work" in what way? And shouldn't it be `self.words`?

Comment: And you sure the counter variable keeps increasing?

Comment: Are you sure this is the actual code? `newmessage.text.split(' ')` isn't valid, there's no `text` attribute on strings. Is `newmessage` meant to be an instance of `NewLabel`?

Answer (score 0):

You could memoize the output of split

```
MC = {}


def wrapper(fn):
    def inner(arg):
        if not MC.has_key(arg):
            MC[arg] = fn(arg)
        return MC[arg]
    return inner

@wrapper
def myfn(x):
    print x

myfn(1)
myfn(1)
myfn(2)
```

So basically what happend is you write your text splitting function like this

```
@wrapper
def split(text):
    return text.split(' ')
```

and everytime you want the split of newmessage.text, you call it split(newmessage.text). The wrapper will first check if the text has already been encountered and return the value if it is or call the function and split it and store it for later use.

You can run the above code here http://codebunk.com/b/-JJzVKR8KgtdaIIsmODh

Answer (score 0):

If your `newmessage` is being modified by other parts of your code that don't need to know about the `NewLabel` instance, I'd probably create a class to encapsulate the `newmessage` behaviour:

```
class Message(object):
    def __init__(self, message):
        self.set_text(message)
    def set_text(self, message):
        self.text = message.split(' ')

newmessage = Message("this is a test hello. this is a test.")
```

And then include it as one of the arguments passed to `NewLabel`:

```
class NewLabel(ButtonBehavior, Label):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        ...
        self.message = kwargs['message']

    def eachwordprint(self, *args):
        words = self.message.text
        print "counter: ", self.counter
        print "word length", len(words)
        ...
```

Whenever you need to change the message, you'd do:

```
newmessage.set_text('this is the new test')
```

However, if you're always setting the message text in parts of the code that *do* know about your `NewLabel`, then just add them directly to the `NewLabel` class:

```
class NewLabel(ButtonBehavior, Label):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        ...
        self.set_text(kwargs['message'])

    def set_text(self, text):
        self.words = text.split(' ')

    def eachwordprint(self, *args):
        words = self.words
        print "counter: ", self.counter
        print "word length", len(words)
        ...
```